# How is it suppose that I use wit.ai if stories are deprecated?

Tags: facebook, chatbot, messenger, wit.ai, botkit

I'm developing a bot using this workflow Glitch Hosting -> BotKit Studio API ->Facebook API -> Wit.AI API. Right now Wit.ai works with my bot, when I check de Logs console (in wit.ai) shows messages that have been sent through messenger, but what I do not understand is how to use wit.ai to analyze the user's message and then send a response.

Answer (score 0):

you parse the incoming json with `intent and`entities`which are under the key`nlp` and then handle it yourself.